# The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found

Tags: themes, dotnetnuke, skin

I built a custom theme for DNN several months ago using the Christoc templates for Visual Studio. I needed to make a small HTML adjustment today so I re-opened the solution and made the change but when I rebuilt the project, I get several build errors, presumably because it no longer recognizes my DNN dll:

> The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I checked my `C:\path_to\dnndev.me\bin\DotNetNuke.dll` and it's still there so I'm not sure why Visual Studio isn't seeing it.

When I built the skin originally, I was running DNN 9.1.1 but have since upgraded to 9.3.2. Could that be causing my issue?

I read [elsewhere](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/533296/scope/posts/dotnetnuke-39-could-not-be-found) that I could be building on the incorrect version of .NET framework but I don't know what version to use for DNN 9.3.2 so I tried several different version with no change in results.

How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

Per the answer here, I rebuilt with .NET 4.7.2 and it did not solve my issue.

**UPDATE 2:**

Okay, so the small change I made was adding another layout page like the Home.ascx and Edit.ascx files that come with the template. If I remove the new layout files, the project builds fine.

What could I be doing wrong when adding a new layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a new layout I had created. I right clicked on the project and selected `Add > New Item` and chose `Web Forms User Control`. This was the wrong way to add a new layout.

I successfully added it by copy/pasting one of the template's pre-existing layouts and renaming it. The project builds fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What you read about the .Net framework version is correct. You need to 4.7.2.

Comment: I rebuilt with 4.7.2 but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, 4.7.2 is required for DNN 9.4.2, not 9.3.2. - Please try to remove DotNetNuke.dll from the references and then add it again.

Comment: Which version is required for 9.3.2?

Comment: I removed both the DotNetNuke.dll and the DotNetNuke.Web.Client.dll with no effect.

Comment: It could also be that the error is caused by another error - maybe some deprecated function or property. Try to solve the errors at the end of the list first, maybe this is the reason... (Sorry for shots in the blue, but as I am trying to help without knowing your setup, it is a bit hard...)

Comment: I have 21 errors and all of them are that it can't find DotNetNuke or  or that Meta, Logo, Copyright, etc. does not exist in DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.

Comment: See the newest update in the question. My issue has something to do with creating a new layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I understand what went wrong. Adding a Web (Forms) User Control is not completely wrong, as a skin (or theme) is a kind of Web User Control, and has the same extension (.ascx).

What you have to do is deleting the code behind file (.ascx.vb or .ascx.cs), and change the first line of the ascx file to

```
<%@ Control language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
```

(But copying another skin file is also a good solution as propably you have most of the references to the skin object already there)